# How can I pass one parameters visible in URL and one more not with Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to pass 2 arguments through url.
The first one is an ID that I want to see in the URL.
The second is a counter but, this time, i don't want to see it in URL.

This arguments come from a function "insert_inventory" and are going to "insert_resort".

I don't know how i can do that. I'm trying with kwargs but that didn't work.

I'm using Django 2.2

urls.py

```
path('insert_resort/<int:id_inventory>/',
      view_resort.insert_resort,
      kwargs={'id_inventory': 'id_inventory',
              'cpt': 'cpt'},
      name='insert-resort'),
```

A part of insert_inventory function

```
def insert_inventory(request)
    #Some code here...

    kwargs_resort = {
        'id_inventory': id_inventory,
        'cpt': 1,
    }
    return HttpResponseRedirect(
        reverse(
            'insert-resort',
            kwargs=kwargs_resort,
        )
    )
```

If someone understands my question and can redirect me on a good practice or a solution, i'll be thankful.

Comment: If you do not want to see data in URL, you should send HTTP POST request.

Comment: i dont think its even logical or else the url path will be misleading. The things you can do is either use a POST method or else use session to hold the cpt value and then use while it redirects

Comment: Where is `insert_inventory` executed from?

Comment: I try to send information with HTTP POST request but I don't know how can i do it with Django. I was thinking there is a good practice for do my job. I will try session.
`insert_inventory` is a form. When he's submit, i'm redirect to `insert_resort`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used session like that

```
request.session['key_counter'] = myvalue
```

When I don't need it anymore, i delete it

```
del request.session['key_counter']
```

I don't know if it's a good practice but that works.
If someone has a better idea, I'm listening.

Thanks for help !